# Python: rasing from except causes finally to execute?

Tags: python, exception

Say I have the following code:

```
try:
    [...]
except:
    raise Exception([...])
finally:
    [code]
```

My question is: if the code in the `try` block raises an exception which is caught in `except`, is `[code]` from the `finally` clause executed since a new exception is raised in the `except` clause? And if so, when is it executed? Before the new exception is raised or after the new exception is propagated through the method stack?

Comment: You probably could have tested this in less time than it took you to write the question...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

an example is worth a 1000 words, why didn't you just try what you've written?

```
>>> def foo():
>>>     try:
>>>         print "2 try block"
>>>         raise Exception("1")
>>>         print "never printed"
>>>     except:
>>>         print "3 first except block"
>>>         raise Exception("2")
>>>     finally:
>>>         print "4 finally block"
>>>     print "end of function"
>>>
>>> try:
>>>     print "1 before foo"
>>>     foo()
>>>     print "never printed too"
>>> except:
>>>     print "5 outter except clause"
1 before foo
2 try block
3 first except block
4 finally block
5 outter except clause
```

> Before the new exception is raised or after the new exception is propagated through the method stack?

so as you can tell from the example, the finally block is called after the except block it has been defined in (i.e. after leaving the `try`/`except`/`finally` block), but before getting to the outer `try`/`except` block.

Which is logical, you want the finally to always be triggered when you exit the `try` block however you exit it, so you can be sure that your code environment is coherent when executing code outside of the `try` statement (whether you're releasing resources, or resetting values, or rolling back/committing modifications...).

Comment: Thank you for your answer and for such a great example!

Answer (score 3):

finally is executed no matter the try block succeeds or the except block is run due to exceptions!

even if your except block raises an exception the new exception will be handled by another try catch handler but after executing the finally block, instead of forming a recursive loop:

```
try:
    try:
        [...]
    except:
        raise Exception([...]) #this is line number xyz
    finally:
        [code]
except:
    [...] #this code will be running after line number xyz
```

Comment: @linkyndy code from finally is executed immediately after the try-catch block terminates no matter what the result is. If you liked my answer, accept it :P